# How do I synchronize the scroll position of two divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have 2 divs sized to a particular width (i.e. 500px). One above the other aligned horizontally.

The top box should hide its scroll bar, the bottom should show a scroll bar and when the user scrolls I'd like the offset of the top box to change to the value of the bottom box. So that when the bottom DIV scrolls horizontally it appears that the top DIV is also scrolling in unison.

I'm happy to do this in Jquery if it makes the process easier.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
$('#bottom').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#top').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Here we are using `.scrollTop()` for all it's worth, getting the `scrollTop` value from the element with scroll-bars, and setting the `scrollTop` for the other element to sync their scroll positions: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop

This assumes that your bottom element has an ID of `bottom` and your top element has an ID of `top`.

You can hide the scroll-bars for the `top` element using CSS:

```
#top {
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/1884/

I suppose I've never really had a reason to do this, but it looks pretty cool in action.

Comment: Ok great example (thank you!). Could you by chance provide a similar example but using the Jquery Scroll Left to make it scroll horizontally?

Comment: @JosephU. :), have you tried replaceing `scrollTop` with `scrollLeft` for both instances?

Comment: @JosephU. Here is an updated JSFiddle that demonstrates using `scrollLeft` instead of `scrollTop`: http://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/1/

Comment: Excellent example here Jasper!

Comment: In the demo fiddle, `overflow` for `#bottom` should really be `overflow-y` to avoid getting the x-scrollbar at the bottom of the div with scroll controls.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same but instead if element IDs, I'd like to use class names. So I added the class "syncScroll" to two of my tables and tried to call your function with
 $('.syncScroll').on('scroll', function() {
         $('.syncScroll').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    })
but it's not working. Is this in general not working with classnames or should I look for other erros in my code?

Answer (score 77):

I know this is an old thread, but maybe this will help someone.
In case if you need to synchronize scrolling in double direction, it's not good enough to just handle both containers' scrolling events and set the scroll value, because then scrolling events are getting into cycle and the scrolling is not smooth (try to scroll vertically by a mouse wheel an example given by Hightom).

Here is an example of how you can check if you are already synchronizing the scroll:

```js
var isSyncingLeftScroll = false;
var isSyncingRightScroll = false;
var leftDiv = document.getElementById('left');
var rightDiv = document.getElementById('right');

leftDiv.onscroll = function() {
  if (!isSyncingLeftScroll) {
    isSyncingRightScroll = true;
    rightDiv.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
  }
  isSyncingLeftScroll = false;
}

rightDiv.onscroll = function() {
  if (!isSyncingRightScroll) {
    isSyncingLeftScroll = true;
    leftDiv.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
  }
  isSyncingRightScroll = false;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.leftContainer {
  float: left;
}

.rightContainer {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="left" class="container leftContainer">
Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</div>
<div id="right" class="container rightContainer">
Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2brahp0m/).

Comment: Perfect... Works great!  Thank you.

Comment: Great, Thank you!!

Comment: A pure javascript solution. Thank you.

Comment: I applied same logic for horizontal scrolls. works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Alright, so I evaluated all of the options presented here, and they all had limitations of one form or another:

- The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9236351/403765) suffers from known issues using the mouse scroll wheel.
- The [next highest upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41998497/403765) does not have scroll wheel issues, but only works for two known elements. If you need more elements, it's not scalable.
- The only solution that showed promise was [Lacho's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51860814/403765), but there were known element references in the code that were not included in the snippet. On the plus side, it had the structure needed for performance, and it's in TypeScript.

I leveraged that to create a reusable version that can work with an unlimited number of elements, and it doesn't require JQuery.

```
function scrollSync(selector) {
  let active = null;
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
      active = e.target;
    });

    element.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
      if (e.target !== active) return;

      document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(function(target) {
        if (active === target) return;

        target.scrollTop = active.scrollTop;
        target.scrollLeft = active.scrollLeft;
      });
    });
  });
}

//RWM: Call the function on the elements you need synced.
scrollSync(".scrollSync");
```

You can check out the JSFiddle for this here: http://jsfiddle.net/gLa2ndur/3. You can see it uses both horizontal and vertical scrolling examples.

The only known limitation is that it might not work on divs of different sizes. I'm sure someone can work on incorporating [Andrew's work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57365748/403765) into this if your use-case finds that necessary (mine does not).

I hope this is helpful to someone!

Comment: it could probably use some beautification, but here's the relative/absolute version: http://jsfiddle.net/2wdbcfjz/37/

Comment: This is a great solution but it still has one flaw. It will not work when a target is programmatically scrolled.

Answer (score 12):

I've been looking for a double direction solution and thanks to you all, your contibutions helped me doing this :

```
$('#cells').on('scroll', function () {
$('#hours').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
$('#days').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());});
```

See on JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/1274/

Hope it's help someone someday :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that prevents this looping problem and achieves a smooth scroll.
This makes sure that only the focused element gets the scroll event.

```
let activePre: HTMLPreElement = null;
document.querySelectorAll(".scrollable-pre").forEach(function(pre: HTMLPreElement) {
    pre.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e: MouseEvent) {
        let pre = e.target as HTMLPreElement;
        activePre = pre;
    });

    pre.addEventListener("scroll", function(e: MouseEvent) {
        let pre = e.target as HTMLPreElement;

        if (activePre !== pre) {
            return;
        }

        if (pre !== versionBasePre) {
            versionBasePre.scrollTop = pre.scrollTop;
            versionBasePre.scrollLeft = pre.scrollLeft;
        }

        if (pre !== versionCurrentPre) {
            versionCurrentPre.scrollTop = pre.scrollTop;
            versionCurrentPre.scrollLeft = pre.scrollLeft;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I used it as the basis for my answer here, which lets you sync an unlimited number of scrollable elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63864273/403765

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answers above, I made a mixed solution that works preferentially for me:

```
var isLeftScrollTopCalled = false;
$('#leftElement').scroll(function (e) {
    if (isRightScrollTopCalled) {
        return isRightScrollTopCalled = false;
    }

    $('#rightElement').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    isLeftScrollTopCalled = true;
});

var isRightScrollTopCalled = false;
$('#rightElement').scroll(function (e) {
    if (isLeftScrollTopCalled) {
        return isLeftScrollTopCalled = false;
    }

    $('#leftElement').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    isRightScrollTopCalled = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that his question was pretty old, but I thought I could leave a jQuery implementation that works much better than using timers. Here, I am using two event listeners like the previously used solutions but, this will use proportions/percentage to sync scrolls for two differently sized div boxes. You can apply this same knowledge to get the position the scrollbars to a Vanilla JS solution. This will make the scrolling between the two divs much smoother.

```
/** Scroll sync between editor and preview **/
// Locks so that only one pane is in control of scroll sync
var eScroll = false;
var pScroll = false;
// Set the listener to scroll
this.edit.on('scroll', function() {
    if(eScroll) { // Lock the editor pane
        eScroll = false;
        return;
    }
    pScroll = true; // Enable the preview scroll

    // Set elements to variables
    let current = self.edit.get(0);
    let other = self.preview.get(0);

    // Calculate the position of scroll position based on percentage
    let percentage = current.scrollTop / (current.scrollHeight - current.offsetHeight);

    // Set the scroll position on the other pane
    other.scrollTop = percentage * (other.scrollHeight - other.offsetHeight);
});
this.preview.on('scroll', function() {
    if(pScroll) { // Lock the preview pane
        pScroll = false;
        return;
    }
    eScroll = true; // Enable the editor scroll

    // Set elements to variables
    let current = self.preview.get(0);
    let other = self.edit.get(0);

    // Calculate the position of scroll position based on percentage
    let percentage = current.scrollTop / (current.scrollHeight - current.offsetHeight);

    // Set the scroll position on the other pane
    other.scrollTop = percentage * (other.scrollHeight - other.offsetHeight);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added two functions with DOM manipulation

```js
function scrollSynchronizeY(element1,element2){
  document.querySelector(element1).addEventListener('scroll',function(e){
    document.querySelector(element2).scrollTop = e.target.scrollTop;
  })
  document.querySelector(element2).addEventListener('scroll',function(e){
    document.querySelector(element1).scrollTop = e.target.scrollTop;
  })
}
function scrollSynchronizeX(element1,element2){
  document.querySelector(element1).addEventListener('scroll',function(e){
    console.log('scrolled left ',e.target.scrollLeft);
    document.querySelector(element2).scrollLeft = e.target.scrollLeft;
  })
  document.querySelector(element2).addEventListener('scroll',function(e){
    document.querySelector(element1).scrollLeft = e.target.scrollLeft;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this question a few days ago. Since I couldn't find an up-to-date solution (should be vanilla JavaScript, should include tests, should smoothly work on mobile), I created a package myself: https://github.com/hirasso/scrollmirror/

```js
new ScrollMirror(document.querySelectorAll('.scroller'));
```

```css
.scrollers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  width: 500px;
  gap: 5px;
}

.scroller {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-inline: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollers">
  <div class="scroller">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex incidunt dicta laudantium eius, provident beatae quas cumque temporibus eum, officia perspiciatis minus, modi eligendi similique? Officiis, veniam! Illum ad quo velit dicta! Voluptatem tenetur nihil deleniti, eveniet, impedit quam excepturi dolor assumenda saepe eius sapiente voluptas ad sunt facilis inventore maiores alias ullam enim quis? Facilis tenetur eveniet nihil quibusdam alias rerum ex fugit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="scroller">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex incidunt dicta laudantium eius, provident beatae quas cumque temporibus eum, officia perspiciatis minus, modi eligendi similique? voluptas iusto doloremque accusantium dicta atque ex, vitae possimus! Aspernatur quas ea similique, tempora cumque ad animi consectetur id minima ducimus, cupiditate quae vel consequuntur repellendus consequatur iure, debitis aperiam non? Nam dolore perferendis vero. Aspernatur quod vero at provident aliquam perspiciatis quam eos obcaecati doloribus temporibus praesentium, quae nihil possimus rem soluta dolorum laborum voluptates sapiente velit porro deleniti molestiae est! Dolorum, asperiores aliquam debitis sed facilis facere cupiditate accusamus! Dolores ex unde amet dicta totam perspiciatis eveniet facere eligendi ratione magnam quia consequuntur eos, nemo voluptates ab at a reiciendis, maiores rerum error velit dignissimos! Repellendus maiores quidem repudiandae amet. Cumque fugit laboriosam harum. Facere totam ipsam magnam molestiae eveniet. Ex unde natus veritatis fuga asperiores sint cumque voluptates quam commodi, veniam ullam in nulla eos rem, consectetur tempora dolore dicta laboriosam dolor ipsum voluptatem. Harum illo minima ea sequi dolorum ipsa eligendi laudantium autem laboriosam? Odit exercitationem quod ea a provident tempora, maxime nam explicabo molestias perferendis sunt iusto. Voluptas omnis, porro aliquam consequatur perspiciatis fugiat ipsam nulla similique reiciendis, doloribus voluptatem sapiente excepturi?</p>
    <p>consectetur tempora dolore dicta laboriosam dolor ipsum voluptatem. Harum illo minima ea sequi dolorum ipsa eligendi laudantium autem laboriosam? Odit exercitationem quod ea a provident tempora, maxime nam explicabo molestias perferendis sunt iusto. Voluptas omnis, porro aliquam consequatur perspiciatis fugiat ipsam nulla similique reiciendis, doloribus voluptatem sapiente excepturi?</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/scrollmirror"></script>
```

Maybe helpful for someone else out there.