# How to move scroll bar

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a floating panel similar to [this site](http://chuabenhxahoi.com.vn). The panel stays in the same place when the scroll bar is moved.

The photo below will describe my problem.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position#Values