# How can I scroll div based on a horizontal scrollbar in another div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a `<div id="topDiv">Some content</div>` which may be extending due to various reason beyond the browser's edge on the right side.
Below that div I have another `<div id=bottomDiv">Some content</div>` that actually generates a horizontal scroll bar if its content goes beyond the browser's edge on the right side.

I'm looking for a jQuery solution that would allow me to scroll/move the topDiv when the user scrolls the bottomDiv using its scroll bar. So that both topDiv & bottomDiv content is always aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a repeat of this question: [How do I synchronize the scroll position of two divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs)

But this answer would involve `scrollLeft()` instead of `scrollTop()`.

```
$('#bottom').scroll(function () {
  $('#top').scrollTop($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wvwLt3s9/

You would have to play around with the syncing of the two to get them to scroll at the rates you want, but this should work.