# Mirror scrolling effect On.Click between two containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, target, scrolltop

At the moment, I am learning how to write in javascript and jquery.I use a code which when you click on the navigation menu it scrolls down to a specific div inside another div. However, I am trying to split this container into two separate ones. So the `Left_Container` will start from the bottom and the `Right_Container` will start from the top. The idea is to create a mirror scrolling between the two containers. While the first one is going down the other to go up. I assume that the mistake is somewhere in the `data-target` but my knowledge isn't enough to fix it by my own. If someone can help me I will be really grateful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".Menu li").on('click', function() {
  $('.Left_Container').animate({
   scrollTop: $($(this).data('target')).position().top +                                       $('.Left_Container').scrollTop()
  }, 'slow');
  $('.Right_Container').animate({
   scrollTop: $($(this).data('target')).position().top +                                       $('.Right_Container').scrollTop()
  }, 'slow');
 });  
});
```

```css
.Wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: purple;
}
.Menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
.Menu li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 4vw;
  line-height: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.Left_Container {
  position: relative;
  width: 43vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.Right_Container {
  position: relative;
  width: 43vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.Box {
  position: relative;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="Menu">
        <li data-target="#Left_A,Right_C">A</li>
        <li data-target="#Left_B,Right_B">B</li>
        <li data-target="#Left_C,Right_A">C</li>
    </div>
    <div class="Left_Container">
      <div class="Box" id="Left_C">
          Box C
      </div>
      <div class="Box" id="Left_B">
          Box B
      </div>
      <div class="Box" id="Left_A">
          Box A
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Left_Container">
      <div class="Box" id="Right_A">
          Box A
      </div>
      <div class="Box" id="Right_B">
          Box B
      </div>
      <div class="Box" id="Right_C">
          Box C
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

George S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy to understand example of two divs that scroll each other in reverse...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

.BoxStyle {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 overflow: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="BoxStyle" id="Box1" onscroll="Box2.scrollTop=(Box2.scrollHeight-this.scrollTop);">box 1
<div style="position:absolute; top:500px;">.</div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="BoxStyle" id="Box2" onscroll="Box1.scrollTop=(Box1.scrollHeight-this.scrollTop);">box 2
<div style="position:absolute; top:500px;">.</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried modifying my code with the example you gave me but there is something strange. When I am scrolling the first div at some point the second div is stuck and doesn't want to scroll anymore. [JsFiddle of the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/nowzbwm8/1/)

Comment: Works ok for me in my Chromium browser. The only minor problem is that the second div doesn't start out at the bottom where it should be so to correct this problem we must set it to go to the bottom from the onset...

You can replace the BODY tag with this...


<body onload="Box2.scrollTop=Box2.scrollHeight;">

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem last week. And I couldn't find a clean vanilla JS solution. That's why I created the package [ScrollMirror](https://github.com/hirasso/scrollmirror).

You can see how to use it in [this related StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77605882/586823) or on the [GitHub README](https://github.com/hirasso/scrollmirror/#usage-example).

Installation:

```
npm install scrollmirror
```

Usage:

```
import ScrollMirror from 'scrollmirror';
new ScrollMirror(document.querySelectorAll('.scroller'));
```