# How to Scroll two div's at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make two div's scroll at the same time?
I have two div's with text, but one div is bigger and I want to scroll both of them at the same time.

Any ideas?

```
.content {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fhq2kmvb/3/)

Comment: Link to existing post on same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I synchronize the scroll position of two divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs)

Answer (score 6):

So u want to scroll both div's at the same time?

Change your CSS to this:

```
.content {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.left{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.right{
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fhq2kmvb/12/

Comment: The thing is, I want to scroll green box while I am on yellow box. Note that yellow box doesn't have enough content to be scrollable. I hope it makes sense?

Answer (score 4):

Wasted 5 hours on this.

I had a similar question.
I wanted to overlap & also scroll.

```
.content {
  position: "relative";
  overflow: "auto";
}
.below{
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  /* width: 100%; */  
}
.above{
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* width: 120%; */
}
```

https://codepen.io/manoharreddyporeddy/pen/XWmpYQL

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that could get you started

**script**

```
$('.left').scroll(function () {
    $('.right').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

**css**

```
.content {
  width: 100%;
}
.left{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 200px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}
.right{
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 200px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```