# Scroll left div and right div at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webix

I have two div elements side by side with scroll.

If i scroll left div automatically right div also should scroll.(Like beyond compare scroll)

```
<div id="leftdiv" style="overflow-y: scroll;"> Left Content</div>
<div id="rightdiv" style="overflow-y: scroll;">Right Content</div>
```

Comment: so what you've tried so far??

Comment: i google it, but i don't find any solution.

Comment: Tried search SO too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I synchronize the scroll position of two divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs)

Comment: Thank you Ricardo. Your link helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#leftdiv").on('scroll', function(evt) {
  $("#rightdiv").scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qyvezhvq/10/

Answer (score 0):

see, I hope this is helpful

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){       
    $( "#leftdiv" ).scroll(function() {         
        if($( "#leftdiv" ).scrollTop() > 0)
        {
            $("#rightdiv").scrollTop($( "#leftdiv" ).scrollTop());  
        }

    }); 
    $( "#rightdiv" ).scroll(function() {            
        if($( "#rightdiv" ).scrollTop() > 0)
        {
            $("#leftdiv").scrollTop($( "#rightdiv" ).scrollTop());  
        }

    });     
});
</script>
```

Thanks.