# Synchronizing the scroll of two div's vertically. (scrolling two div's together)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, bootstrap-4

I have a text in a box which is scrollable and outside of this box are also the headings located which belong to certain paragraphs/sections in the text. Now I want that when I scroll the text inside the box, the headings outside the box also scrolls. I am looking for a way to link certain text part to a certain heading so that it scrolls with the text.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

And here is my code for this section:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="section">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <img src="images/unterschiede.png" id="unterschiedeImg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div class="col-sm-2 padding0 hidden-xs">
                    <p class="ij-p heading-p text-center margintop200">Schreibweise </p>
                    <p class="ij-p heading-p text-center margintop320">Grundformen</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 onlyPaddingRight20 ">
                    <div class="borderwhite">
                        <p class="ij-p heading-p visible-xs">Schreibweise</p>
                        <p class="ij-p">Persisch ist im Deutschen die Bezeichnung der Amtssprache im Iran. Offiziell heißt sie dort Zaban-e Farsi «زبان فارسی». Farsi gehört zur indoeuropäischen Sprachfamilie und wird der iranischen Untergruppe zugeordnet.</p>
                        <p class="ij-p">Die Farsi Schriftzeichen werden <a class="basicLink" onclick="displayToggel()">von rechts nach links geschrieben und gelesen</a>. Die zahlen jedoch werden wie im Lateinischen von rechts nach links geschrieben, „Parsi“ und „Persisch“ sind beide Synonyme von „Farsi“, nur dass sie genauer gesagt in Bezug auf die zeitgeschichtliche Sprachentwicklung von Farsi verwendet werden. Der Begriff „Parsi“ hat sich wegen des fehlenden P-Lauts im Laufe der Jahrhunderte zu „Farsi“ verwandelt. Das älteste Beweisdokument des Altpersischen lässt sich auf das 6. Jh. v. Chr. zurückverfolgen. </p>
                        <p class="ij-p heading-p visible-xs">Grundformen</p>
                        <p class="ij-p">Das persische Alphabet „Alebfa“ besteht aus 32 Buchstaben, die man in 18 Grundformen einteilen kann. Es ähnelt sehr dem arabischen Alphabet, wurde aber modifiziert. Konkret wurden vier weitere Buchstaben hinzugefügt und zwei Buchstaben in der Schreibweise verändert. Diakritischezeichen werden selten in der persischen Sprache eingesetzt. Ausnahmen: Fremdwörter, Grundschulbücher, der heilige Koran.

                            </br>
                            </br>Anatomie </br>
                            </br>Glyphen im Lateinischen stehen normalerweise auf einer Grundlinie mit fünf vertikalen Hauptbezugsebenen: Grundlinie, x-Höhe, Oberlänge, Unterlänge und Kappenhöhe.  Im Gegensatz dazu sind die persischen Glyphen weniger eingeschränkt, da den Typedesignern eine größere Anzahl an unsichtbaren typografischen Ebenen zur Verfügung stehen. Die kalligraphischen Regeln für sich in typografische Richtlinien zu übersetzen.
                            </br>Anstelle des klassischen Grundlinienaufbaus der lateinischen Schrift, werden in der persischen Anatomie für die Oberlänge die Begriffe Himmel 1 und Himmel 2 (خط ارش), für die x-Höhe die Augenhöhe 1 (کرسی بصری) für die Grundlinie (خط کرسی)der Begriff Augenhöhe 2 und für die Unterlänge der Begriff Boden (خط پایین) verwendet. Das Liniensystem der persischen Anatomie, lässt sich zudem durch zwei weitere unsichtbare Linien ergänzen Imaginäre Ebene (کرسی فرضی), wodurch dem Schriftgestalter eine Vielzahl an kreativen gestalterischen Möglichkeiten offen steht. Eine humanistische Schriftart, die von den kursiven Naskh-Skripten abgeleitet ist, kann bis zu zwölf imaginäre typografische Ebenen verwenden. Das bedeutet, dass Schriftgestalter, die aus dem lateinischen Schriftraum stammen, ein gewisses Grundwissen über persische kalligraphische Stile und Systeme besitzen müssen, um kreativ sein zu können. Die Schriftzeichen haben eine Kombination aus verbundenen und eigenständigen Buchstaben. Es gibt Regeln, für die Buchstabenformen gestreckt (Variabel) werden können.</p>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I synchronize the scroll position of two divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs)

Answer (score 0):

I think for that design the simplest thing might be to keep the headings inside the same div and use a negative left margin to give the illusion that they are outside. Any JS solution would require using a scroll listener, which would likely cause performance issues if not throttled, or look janky if throttled. I don't have time to code up an example version but hopefully that helps