# setting div to height: 100% makes scrollbar disabled

Tags: html, css, height, scrollbar, overflow

I have the following code where I want to make the 2 div tags take up all the available height the browser offers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .left {
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: green;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        .right {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            display: block;
            width: 50%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            Text
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            Text
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have decided to do this setting height:100%, but this disables the individual scrollbars of the divs - does anyone know how to make the scrollbars work and having the divs take up the height of the browser? (I don't want to hardcode something like height: 700px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "take up all the available height the browser offers" you mean you want the `div`s to take up 100% of the viewport. The reason this is not happening in your code is that you have only set the height of the `div`s to 100%. This means they will take up the full height of their parent element, `.container`, but you have not set the height of that element (or the height of its parent, `body`, or the height of its parent, `html`). You need to set the height of all three of those elements.

In addition, I would explicitly set the margin on `body`. If you do not, then it defaults to `8px` in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge, but it may default to some other number in older versions or other browsers. If you set the margin to 0, then for `html` and `body` you can set the height to 100%. If you want the margin of `body` to be `8px` or some other non-zero number, then you need to account for that in the height of `html` and `body`. (e.g. `height: calc(100% - 8px)`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .left {
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: green;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        .right {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            display: block;
            width: 50%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            Text
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            Text
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks good cheers - just one thing though, is it possible to retain the normal scrollbar that would scroll through both div tags?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want there to be scrollbars on the individual divs AND a scrollbar on the entire document? Or do you just want there to be a scrollbar on the document?

Comment: scrollbars on the individual divs and a scrollbar on the entire document

Comment: It kind of seems like those are mutually exclusive, no? If you can scroll both the divs with the normal scrollbar, then why would the individual divs also need scrollbars? I must not understand what you are looking for. Please try to explain as clearly and precisely as possible.

Comment: so each div tag can be scrolled individually, or if the user desires, they can scroll both at the same time

Comment: I don't believe that can be done with pure CSS. That's simply not the default behavior of scrollbars. I'm not saying it's impossible, but it will probably require some JavaScript. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs) might be a good starting point.